# MVC can't access Models in Razor View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The project name is MVCMultipleModelTypes

```
@using MVCMultipleModelTypes.Models
@model Empl...beeeeeeeeepp.....
```

Does anyone know why i can't access the Models in the View?
I loaded the project in Visual Studio 2015 and 2013 and same thing. The other projects work fine.

The pictre should tell the whole story.
[image: Can't Access Models]

Comment: Have you tried building your solution and then closing and opening the view again?

Comment: Check the namespace of `Employee.cs`. Probably your intellisense is broken, which didn't mean that mvc can't access models.

Comment: Can you show us the definition of `Empl...beeeeeeeeepp.....`, is it `public`?

Comment: I did Clean Solution, Rebuild, Closed, Reopen, same thing.

Namespace is:    namespace MVCMultipleModelTypes.Models
{
    class Employee
    {

Comment: Thanks Coulton!! I was loosing my mind! That was the issue. Classes were not public. All good now :)

Comment: Glad to have helped. Feel free to mark as correct if you deem appropriate.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class needs to be defined as **public** for you to access it in the view.

```
public class Employee
{
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
}
```